# Generalizing the formula between Wu class and the Steenrod square

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homological-algebra, characteristic-classes, steenrod-algebra

I know that on the tangent bundle of $M^d$, the corresponding Wu class and the Steenrod square satisfy

> $$
> Sq^{d-j}(x_j)=u_{d-j} x_j,  \text{ for any } x_j \in H^j(M^d;\mathbb Z_2) .
> \tag{eq.1}$$

This is also called Wu formula.

I also obtain the Wu class as
\begin{align}
u_0&=1, 
\ \ \ \ \
u_1=w_1, 
\ \ \
u_2=w_1^2+w_2, 
 \\
u_3&=w_1w_2, 
\ \ \ \ \
u_4=w_1^4+w_2^2+w_1w_3+w_4, 
 \\
u_5&=w_1^3w_2+w_1w_2^2+w_1^2w_3+w_1w_4.
\end{align}

I also know the related Steenrod relation 
$$
 Sq^n(xy)=\sum_{i=0}^n Sq^i(x)Sq^{n-i}(y).
$$

I am looking for a generalization of (eq.1), such that

- the $x_j \in H^j(M^d;\mathbb Z_2)$ is replaced by a more general

  > $$
  > X_j \in H^j(M^d;\mathbb Z_{m})
  > $$
- the Steenrod square $Sq$ is replaced by

> $$\beta_{(n,m)}:H^*(-,\mathbb Z_{m})\to H^{*+1}(-,\mathbb Z_{n})$$

is the Bockstein homomorphism associated to the extension 
$$\mathbb Z_n\stackrel{\cdot m}{\to}\mathbb Z_{nm}\to\mathbb Z_m$$ where $\cdot m$ is the group homomorphism given by multiplication by $m$. In particular, $$\beta_{(2,2^n)}=\frac{1}{2^n}\delta\mod2.$$

**Question 1**: What will be a **generalization** of (eq.1), when we replace the 
$$Sq^{1}=\beta_{(2,2)} \text{
to  }
\beta_{(n,m)},$$
and replace the 
$$x_j \in H^j(M^d;\mathbb Z_2) \text{
to  }
X_j \in H^j(M^d;\mathbb Z_{m})?$$

> **Question 2**: More specifically, what will be a **generalization** of (eq.1), when we 
>   $$ \text{ replace the } Sq^{1}=\beta_{(2,2)} \text{
> to  }
> \beta_{(2,4)},$$
>   and 
>   $$\text{ replace the } x_2 \in H^2(M^d;\mathbb Z_2) \text{
> to  }
> X_2 \in H^2(M^d;\mathbb Z_{4})?$$
>   Could we simply the relations (like (eq.1) formula between Wu class and the Steenrod square
>   $$
> \beta_{(2,4)}(X_2)=?
> $$
>   or
>   $$
> \beta_{(2,4)}(X_2 \cup X_j \cup X_{k})=?
> $$
>   where $X_j \in H^j(M^d;\mathbb Z_{4})$, similarly for $X_k$.

Comment: Possibly related question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/320907/97265